# Forms loosing caption on W10

Tags: winapi, windows-10, apl, dyalog

I'm sorry, this will be a no-code question, but I think it is still the right place to ask. I'm using the (unfortunately) not so famous language APL and am having problems running my apps under W10 - the forms are shown without a caption:
[image: form without caption]

Only when I switch focus to another app, it gets visible:
[image]

So, without going too much into the details, has anyone come across this before (in other languages on the Windows10-platform) and are there perhaps any new settings or events that need to be considered? *(I discussed this with Dyalog, the developers of that environment, but they seem pretty sure that they are unable to address this...)*

Comment: Does your code do anything with the non-client area? I ask because that is certainly not using the defaults. Consider adding the winapi tag to this question. The people that frequent that tag may have seen this before.

Comment: Thanks for the winapi-suggestion, have added it. As far as *my code* is concerned, nothing is being done with the non-client-area. Perhaps the APL-Environment does, but as a dev I wouldn't know that or couldn't affect it (I assume)...

Comment: I would try a caption of just "Betrag" (without ö, ü, usw.) just in case there is some strange encoding going on.

Comment: Been there, done that, did not change ;-)

Comment: @MBaas - I assumed that you weren't doing anything with the non-client area, but I had to ask anyway.

Comment: *"as a dev I wouldn't know"* - That's a pretty odd statement. If not a developer, who else would know?

Comment: I'm an APL-Developer. To interact with Windows, I depend on the commands the APL-Implementor provides and I do not need to understand the mechanics of these when using them. To me, that does not sound odd, but describes anyone not working in bytecode ;-) Sometimes there is a rather high level of abstraction between dev and bytes (as in APL, fortunately), sometimes it is thinnet (C).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've been struggling with this for wks now, but suddenly I found the solution: I was using a '`3D`'-property of the form (set to value '`Dialog`') and when I removed this, everything looked good :-)

Comment: Michael, thanks for posting this answer. I think I have the same problem!

Comment: Cool - I'm happy it helps ;-)